# submitting two action with one form and one submit button

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have a script that insert into the database ( form ) what I want to do is to send another action  to another section after the insert . thanks in advance

Comment: your user name is apt, as this is a very lazy question

Comment: i want to submit two actions in one form ! @Dagon

Comment: Why use 2 actions? Just put all of the code you want to run into a single action... your question doesn't even make sense.

Comment: if you mean the form attribute, then there can only be one action. if by action you means something broader then there are many possibilities - as it stands the question is not clear.

Comment: for exmeple when i press the button submit I excute two actions at the same time !

Comment: I think the question makes sense, it just indicates you have some refactoring to do. Modularise each block of action code in a function/method somewhere, and then for this particular form, call both of them. It's hard to advise, however, since we don't have the two pieces of form handling code you have currently - edit them into your question?

Comment: i don't think he actully means form action as in  the action attribute. but im still just guessing as the OP refuses to explain. @LazyBrain when the form is submitted you can run as much code as you like 1 'action' or a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should have to one submit form using Ajax after ajax request is success then you can submit another form.

Please mention whole code you want to submit form one by one...

Comment: Good answer sir ji..........kem cho